# Rails - Execute ajax call without form and link_to, pure jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have some div, and when user hover this div, I want to execute some ajax call, trigger some action and write to database that someone hovered that div.

Without forms and link_to, pure jQuery.

I need the simplest possible example :)

Comment: Have you tried anything or should we start from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a new model and controller for logs called HoverLogger (or whichever you like). That way you can separate the logic and be RESTful when it comes to creating logs by calling create action of HoverLogger controller.

Assuming the desired div has class *.hoverable*:

```
$(".hoverable").hover(
    function () {
        // send ajax when mouse enters hoverable object
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/hover_logger",
            data: {logged: true}, // pass any additional parameters if you need
            success: function(msg) {
                console.log(msg); // do something on success e.g. console log the message
            }
        });
    },
    function () {
        // do something when mouse leaves hoverable object
    }
);
```

Log the event in your *create* action:

```
def create
    HoverLogger.create!(user_id: current_user.id)
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :nothing => true }
    end
end
```

*HoverLogger* will keep track of user_id and timestamps. Also create routes for HoverLogger create method.

Comment: There is a few syntax errors, but that's in general correct answer! Thx

Comment: You forgot to fix syntax error with success block. Needs to look like this:
success: function(msg) {
                            console.log(msg); 
                        }

Answer (score 1):

Working code based on selected solution

```
  $(".hoverable").hover(function(){
                console.log("hovered");
                  $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "/vastrodex",
                        data: {vastroman: $(this).attr('id'), vastrodexCount: 1}, // pass any additional parameters if you need
                        success: function(msg) {
                            console.log(msg); // do something on success e.g. console log the message
                        }
                    });
              },function(){
            });
```